# How to disable 3G USB Modem internal storage from being loaded by linux kernel?

Tags: linux, usb, boot, storage, modem

I've got a problem with my 3G modem [Huawei E122].
It has internal storage and kernel assigns a device [/dev/sdX] to it.
Because of that, every second time my machine will not boot - kernel panic - as my usb hdd gets assigned /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sda.
I cannot use LABEL nor UUID in root= kernel parameter, as it is only available when using initrd, and I can't use it - I am using Debian on my router - mips architecture machine.
I have to prevent this from happening, as my router has to start everyday and I have to be sure it works ok. I don't have physical access to restart it when something goes wrong.
I don't use my modem internal storage, there's no SD card inserted. However kernel detects the reader and loads it.
I can not prevent loading od usb drivers since my hdd is on USB as well.

I will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: http://3g-modem.wetpaint.com/page/Huawei+AT-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the "ZeroCD" feature, which can be done with "usb_modeswitch", available for Debian.

See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/usb_modeswitch.1.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's actually how I did it.

Comment: You should add in your answer how to do that.